# Individual icons for each activity in android

Tags: android-layout

I have 4 activities in a single application. Each application can be launched individually. I would like to associate different icons for each activity. I have created the required icons for different resolutions and placed them in the drawable directory. In the AndroidManifest.xml, I have an icon defined for the application using Android:Icon as a default icon. In the activity group I entered the Android:Icon with a different icon. It does not seem to make a difference.

Please provide some guidance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show different icons in Actionbar, then you can add below given code in your activity's oncreate method..

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```